# how to resolve an error like non numeric argument to binary argument?

Tags: r

While computing SST by typing the command

```
SST= sum((wineTest Price mean(wine Price))^2)
```

im getting an error stating

> non numeric argument to binary operator

```
winetest$Price
#[1] 6.9541 6.4979

wine$Price
 7.4950 8.0393 7.6858 6.9845 6.7772 8.0757 6.5188 8.4937 7.3880 6.7127
 7.3094 6.2518 7.7443 6.8398 6.2435 6.3459 7.5883 7.1934 6.2049 6.6367
 6.2941 7.2920 7.1211 6.2587 7.1860

SST= sum((winetest$Price ~ mean(wine$Price))^2)
```

error im getting is

> Error in (winetest$Price ~ mean)^2 : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: one of them is probably a factor. try doing `class(winetest$Price)` and if it is use `winetest$Price  <- as.numeric(as.character(winetest$Price))`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you wrote

> winetest$Price ~ mean(wine$Price)
>   ?

And don't you mean

> winetest$Price - mean(wine$Price) ?

In the first case, you have a formula.